# Symbolic Logic Proof of Associativity

Tags: logic, proof-writing, foundations, associativity

I am currently a math student in cal $b$. I know a super intelligent person that is trying to teach me symbolic logic. We've been doing okay until we've hit associativity. My "teacher" (the intelligent one) said it wasn't proved in his class and he's never seen a proof for it (that doesn't use demorgans laws). I'd love to see a proof without using DeMorgan's laws.

So If anyone knows it here's what I'd like to see.

Prove $pv(qvr)\Rightarrow(pvq)vr$

I have most of the basic theorems and such including commutivity and the contrapositive proved, but no DeMorgan's.

Thanks guys, Have fun!!

Comment: A truth table will clinch it. Boring, but not too hard (only 8 rows), and guaranteed to work.

Comment: It would be interesting to see a proof tree for this.

Comment: Isn't associativity an axiom of propositional logic?

Comment: I have no idea why you would think DeMorgan would even help with this ... Anyway, a basic truth-table will do the trick.

Comment: @Bram28, If you're studying a formal deduction system (e.g. [Natural Deduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_deduction)) then it's not trivial at all that truth tables would give the same results. (See some discussion on wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus#Soundness_and_completeness_of_the_rules).)

Comment: @MarkS. I don't understand why a truth-table would give a different result (namely, that the two statements are indeed equivalent) than a formal proof would show, unless the proof system is unsound or incomplete of course.

Comment: @Bram28 Of course every standard deduction system for propositional logic is sound and complete, but if you're interested in proving things from the standpoint of the deduction system, going through the metaproof that truth tables always work is much longer than just proving the claim directly in your deduction system.

Comment: @MarkS. I still don't understand ... truth-tables seem pretty easy compared to some proof systems. In fact, I see in your post that with that particular proof system used there the proof seems pretty involved.

Comment: @Bram28, Truth tables are absolutely easy to use, which is why a textbook in logic might spend time giving a metaproof that they give the same answers as the deduction system used in the book (by showing soundness and completeness). But at the high-school level, it's common just to say "it's intuitively obvious that these would give the same results as things like modus ponens" and call it a day.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55803/discussion-between-mark-s-and-bram28).

Comment: @MarkS. Oh, I see now what you mean! Yes, it is indeed not obvious that any proof system would reach the same conclusions as a truth table.  But since truth-tables reflect the very semantical definitions of the logical operators involved, I would say that the task is to show a specific proof system is sound and complete, rather than to show that a truth-table is sound and complete: a truth-table systematically explores all possible truth-assignments ... Which is exactly the basis of how we define our semantics. ... Continued...

Comment: @MarkS. In other words, a truth-table, by its very method of exhaustively exploring all truth-assignments, is automatically sound and complete (if one gets the wrong answer, it is because one made a mechanical mistake in evaluating the statements involved). But for a proof system it is not at all obvious that it would soundly and completely capture the defined semantics of the operators involved, which is why all the meta-level proofs are for proof systems. Put differently yet: if a truth-table and a proof system reach different conclusions, then I blame the proof system, not the truth-table.

Comment: @Bram28, I agree with what you said, but I assume the OP was not looking for a truth table/semantics explanation since they mentioned DeMorgan's laws and this would be much easier to do if you allow truth tables.

Comment: @MarkS. OK, that makes sense! That was not clear to me from the question, but I can understand you interpreted it that way!

Comment: @MarkS. Just added my own formal proof!

Comment: @MarkS. Also added an algebraic proof. Given the reference to DeMorgan, maybe that is what the OP was looking for ...

Comment: @aucbrink  Please see the comments, answers, and the fact that your question has been put On Hold:  can you please specify what kind of proof you are looking for? Thanks!

Comment: I see. Yes, I failed to mention that I wanted to avoid truth tables, just because I wanted the algebraic proof. Also yes I've been working in Natural Deduction. I failed to mention all that as I still have tons to learn about all this proofy stuff. I will add this info to my question.

Comment: I will have an update to my question soon. Thanks guys for all your help, one of the proofs in particular is really helpful, I just need to prove one of the equivalencies.

Comment: I found something that works (or at least satisfies my curiosity)! Thanks for your help! The proof that mentions exportation is particularly helpful.

Comment: To explain the vague entry, I had no idea there where so many different methods and systems of proofs and have yet to learn what system my "teacher" and I are using. I have a ton to learn, but thanks so much guys!

Answer (score 3):

To prove $p\lor(q\lor r)$ implies $(p\lor q)\lor r$, assume $p\lor(q\lor r)$ is true, and then, using that assumption, show that $(p\lor q)\lor r$ is true.

Thus, assume $p\lor(q\lor r)$ is true.

Then $p$ is true, or $q \lor r$ is true.

Suppose first that $p$ is true.

Then the truth of $p$ implies the truth of $p \lor q$, which in turn implies the truth of $(p\lor q)\lor r$, as required, so this case is done.

Next suppose $q \lor r$ is true.

Consider two subcases ...

Suppose first that $q\,$ is true

Can you finish it?

Answer (score 1):

The OP has not specified what sort of deduction system they're using ([natural deduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_deduction)?), a computer-verified proof is available at [this page on Metamath](http://us.metamath.org/mpegif/pm1.5.html).

Basically, the proof steps are:

1. A tautology version of [disjunction introduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_introduction) lets us write $\varphi\to(\varphi\lor\chi)$
2. An "in the [consequent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consequent)" version allows us to introduce $\psi$ to the above to get $\varphi\to\left(\psi\lor(\varphi\lor\chi)\right)$
3. The other tautology version lets us write $\chi\to(\varphi\lor\chi)$
4. An "on both sides" version allows us to introduce $\psi$ to both sides of the above to get $(\psi\lor\chi)\to\left(\psi\lor(\varphi\lor\chi)\right)$
5. Finally, a theorem about combining two different implications with disjunction of the [antecedents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antecedent_(logic)) lets us take the things from lines 2 and 4 to get the desired $\left(\varphi\lor(\psi\lor\chi)\right)\to\left(\psi\lor(\varphi\lor\chi)\right)$

This proof and its required theorems have been verified in a certain system with only a few axioms discovered by Jan Łukasiewicz ([Wikipedia's explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus#Example_1._Simple_axiom_system), [Metamath's explanation](http://us.metamath.org/mpegif/mmset.html#scaxioms)). The proof ultimately relies on a list of things* that are all numbered less than 400 except for [orim12i #504](http://us.metamath.org/mpegif/orim12i.html) and [orim2i #506](http://us.metamath.org/mpegif/orim2i.html). Since DeMorgan's laws are [#476](http://us.metamath.org/mpegif/ianor.html), [#477](http://us.metamath.org/mpegif/anor.html), [#478](http://us.metamath.org/mpegif/ioran.html), and [#484](http://us.metamath.org/mpegif/oran.html), this proof doesn't use DeMorgan's laws.

---

*Unfortunately, it's not feasible (certainly not readable) to reproduce the entire tree down to the axioms, but I can list what is used. Specifically, the proof relies on: the four syntax definitions that say its valid to use logical symbols ([negations](http://us.metamath.org/mpegif/wn.html), [implications](http://us.metamath.org/mpegif/wi.html), [biconditionals](http://us.metamath.org/mpegif/wb.html), and [disjunctions](http://us.metamath.org/mpegif/wo.html)), the axioms and deduction rule ([Simp](http://us.metamath.org/mpegif/ax-1.html), [Frege](http://us.metamath.org/mpegif/ax-2.html), [Transp.](http://us.metamath.org/mpegif/ax-3.html), and [Modus Ponens](http://us.metamath.org/mpegif/ax-mp.html)), [the definition of or in terms of negation and implication](http://us.metamath.org/mpegif/df-or.html), and the following 63 theorems:

$\begin{matrix}
\text{a1i}&\text{mpdd}&\text{con1i}&\text{sylbi}\\
\text{a2i}&\text{pm2.43i}&\text{con3d}&\text{bi2}\\
\text{mpd}&\text{syl6c}&\text{con3rr3}&\text{bicom1}\\
\text{syl}&\text{con4d}&\text{pm3.2im}&\text{bicomi}\\
\text{mpi}&\text{pm2.21d}&\text{impi}&\text{biimpri}\\
\text{mp2}&\text{pm2.21}&\text{expi}&\text{pm2.53}\\
\text{id}&\text{pm2.24}&\text{simprim}&\text{pm2.54}\\
\text{idd}&\text{notnot2}&\text{simplim}&\text{orrd}\\
\text{a1d}&\text{con2d}&\text{bi1}&\text{jaoi}\\
\text{a2d}&\text{mt2d}&\text{bi3}&\text{olc}\\
\text{sylcom}&\text{nsyl3}&\text{impbii}&\text{orc}\\
\text{syl5com}&\text{con2i}&\text{impbidd}&\text{orcd}\\
\text{com12}&\text{notnot1}&\text{impbid21d}&\text{olcd}\\
\text{syl5}&\text{con1d}&\text{impbid}&\text{orim12i}\\
\text{syl6}&\text{mt3d}&\text{dfbi1}&\text{orim2i}\\
\text{pm2.27}&\text{nsyl2}&\text{biimpi}&\text{}\\
\end{matrix}$

Answer (score 0):

From your question it is not clear what kind of proof you are looking for, so I will give a couple of different proofs.

First, a formal semantical one.  That is, using the basic truth-functional definition of $\lor$:

$p \lor (q \lor r)$ is false iff

both $p$ and $q \lor r$ are false iff

$p$, $q$, and $r$ are all false iff

both $p \lor q$ and $q$ are false iff

$(p \lor q) \lor r$ is false

This of course also means that $p \lor (q \lor r)$ is true iff $(p \lor q) \lor r$ is true. Hence, they are equivalent.

Second, a formal derivation or formal proof. Now, there are many different proof systems, so if you were looking for one of these, you should have specified the inference rules that would be allowed, but in the absence of that, here is a formal derivation style proof in a fairly standard Fitch-style natural deduction type formal proof:

[image]

Finally, given your comment *not* to use DeMorgan, I suspect that you are looking for an algebraic proof. Now again, that means that you will have to tell us what equivalences we are allowed to use, but let's assume the following fairly standard equivalences:

**Commutation**

$p \land q \Leftrightarrow q \land p$

$p \lor q \Leftrightarrow q \lor p$

**Double Negation**

$\neg \neg p \Leftrightarrow p$

**Implication**

$p \rightarrow q \Leftrightarrow \neg p \lor q$

**Exportation**

$p \rightarrow (q \rightarrow r) \Leftrightarrow (p \land q) \rightarrow r$

With these, you can do the following:

$p \lor (q \lor r) \Leftrightarrow$ (Commutation)

$p \lor (r \lor q) \Leftrightarrow$ (Double Negation x 2)

$\neg \neg p \lor (\neg \neg r \lor q) \Leftrightarrow$ (Implication x 2)

$\neg p \rightarrow (\neg r \rightarrow q) \Leftrightarrow$ (Exportation)

$(\neg p \land \neg r) \rightarrow q) \Leftrightarrow$ (Commutation)

$(\neg r \land \neg p) \rightarrow q) \Leftrightarrow$ (Exportation)

$\neg r \rightarrow (\neg p \rightarrow q) \Leftrightarrow$ (Implication x 2)

$\neg \neg r \lor (\neg \neg p \lor q) \Leftrightarrow$ (Double Negation x 2)

$r \lor (p \lor q) \Leftrightarrow$ (Commutation)

$(p \lor q) \lor r$